# Is it possible to generate a row/sequence of numbers with text nodes without having to type out each number?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I have a mesh line. On the left, you can see the x-values in the position attribute. I want to use those x-values and display them as text by using the text nodes. Without having to type out each number.

Or, is it possible to generate any sequence of numbers with text nodes?

Comment: AFAIK not in GN at the moment. But you can do this with Animation nodes if you are open for this add-on - which is just amazing by the way.

Comment: Thank you Chris. Can you link animation nodes into a GN node tree?

Comment: no you can't. But AN puts the result in a collection, and this collection can be used by GN. So it is in fact connected (somehow).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node setup:

[image]

By changing the integer value you can decide how much numbers should be generated. The object transform output isn't really necessary. I just put it in that you can see the numbers.

result:

[image]

[image]

> Note: Animation nodes is so friendly, it even puts the resulting texts
> in an own collection, which you can use in GN.

[image]

---

So here you see a combination of GN + AN.

Because AN is executed automatically, every change in AN will reflect in GN.

So i distributed the numbers on a cube randomly, and as you can see, if i change the number of numbers, it will be changed in GN too.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Chris, you are a very knowledgeable person.

Comment: @MatheMatics: Thank you very much! If my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left to my answer. i updated my answer with a simple GN + AN setup gif.

Comment: Unfortunately these nodes don't seem to exist anymore in Blender 3.2. There is a Value to  String node but that only takes a single value as an input - not a field, so can only create on integer at a time

Comment: @RajeshJAdvani: about what nodes are you talking? all these nodes are still available....

Comment: Most of the nodes in the first diagram - Loop Input, Convert to Text, Text Object Output - aren't there in Geonodes in Blender 3.2. Since nodes weren't removed after 3.0, I'm guessing you either have an add-on that provides these, or an older version of Blender?

Comment: as i wrote, it is a combination of AN (animation nodes) and geometry nodes. What you see is the free animation-nodes-add-on.