# How to visually number meshes with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have 26 meshes for each letter of alphabet.
I want to put a number directly under each one of them.
How can I do it with geometry nodes?
Thanks.

[image: ABC]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple setup in Geometry Nodes like so:

[image]

Notice the uneven positioning of numbers due to uneven Y coordinate of origins:

[image]

You could combat this, but I don't know if you even need, and if you want to support changing number of objects, or a large number of objects, look into this answer:

[Geonode : Display instances scales as text](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/293844/60486)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's very close!

Comment: Yeah, ideally I have to combat this unevenness, but I don't even understand how to copy your answer correctly, so this combat will be in future somewhere.

Comment: @Loodle I uploaded the .blend file so you can investigate everything, one thing you need to do is to create a collection (select your letters, then press M key). It's possible in your projects origins are more reasonably positioned (I have them all around because I've set the origin to centers of geometry).